# How can save Crystal Report as pdf in server folder in mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports

I can generate the Pdf but I want to save the pdf in folder before show to the view.
I have read many articles but I did not find any proper solution.
Here is my code.

```
            ReportDocument rd = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
            rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "BillInformationReport.rpt"));

            rd.SetDataSource(ds);
            
            Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(ms);
            Byte[] fileBuffer = ms.ToArray();

            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", fileBuffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(fileBuffer);
            rd.Close();
            rd.Dispose();
           
            return null;
```

Comment: This code will attempt to send the PDF to the browser for downloading. Is that what you wanted? If so, what goes wrong exactly?

Comment: No, I do not want it. first I want the pdf file to be saved in a folder then it goes to the browser. @ADyson

Comment: A folder on your server you mean?

Comment: yes. I want It.

Comment: Just Google "c# save memorystream to file" if you want to do that. No need for us to repeat ourselves

Comment: But here I can't find the file name.

Comment: ?? If you are doing the operation to save to a file to disk in your code, then you can choose whatever filename you want. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: i did not get it searching on memorystream to file. How Can Generate pdf file and save to disk. my code Genreate pdf to the  browser.@ADyson

Comment: The memory stream contains the exported file data in PDF format, correct? As per the command in your code which creates the stream. So all you have to do is save that stream's data into a file on disk - as I said you can easily google existing examples of that process.

Comment: Can u provide exactly demo code for this.@ADyson

Comment: why? You can find it by searching easily. What did you try? What went wrong? Where are you stuck? Please first share **your** attempt at doing this task, based on your research. Then explain what goes wrong and we can try to help you fix the specific issue. There's really no point in me repeating generic information which already exists. Type "c# save memorystream to file" into any search engine and you'll get lots of help already.